# In WoW, what can I do with BOP items obtained by 'Greed'?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In dungeons, I see most people choose 'Greed' for everything they don't 'Need', even for BOP items. If that person is not an enchanter, is it the only option to sell these BOP items to vendor? Can I make any use of a BOP recipe of a profession that I don't learn?

Also it seems there is a rare chance when I select 'Greed' for a blue item, I get it as BOE instead of BOP. What exactly is the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BoP equipment that you cannot use, can either be disenchanted or sold to a NPC.
BoP recipes can not be disenchanted and thus have to be sold to NPCs. You *could* however decide to learn the appropriate profession later on and use the recipe then.

Generally, when a dungeon/raid party has an enchanter, people will abandon the 'Greed' roll for BoP items and let the enchanter perform a greed roll; this ensures that people who actually 'Need' it can still get it, without having to compete with the enchanter, whose need is lower. Depending on how the party is organized, the members may also `/roll` in order to determine who will get the enchanting materials (although I have never actually seen such a party).
Of course, this is assuming the enchanter has made him/herself known to the other party members.

Blue items are not necessarily BoP and neither are Purple items, therefore there is **no** chance for an uncommon or rarer item to be BoE instead of BoP. They are either BoP or BoE and that's that.

Comment: The current implementation has an additional roll named 'Disenchant'. This is only available if the group has an enchanter at the required disenchant level for the item which is being rolled for. This allows non-enchanters to select 'Disenchant' instead of 'Greed' and receive the enchanting materials instead of the item.

Comment: And additionally, which option you should select is mostly based on your servers economy. If you need gold, sometimes the item will sell for more than the materials generated. If you need enchanting materials, selling it might still be more beneficial if the materials don't sell for much.

Comment: Sorry for the 3 comments in a row. For information, Patch 3.3 implemented the disenchant button.

Comment: @NickBayley Thank you very much, I didn't know this. I stopped playing WoW somewhere between Burning Crusade and Wrath of the Lich King.

Comment: Also, the other option that can be carried out with BoP items you dont need, is to use it for Transmogrifications (making an item you wear look like the mentioned BoP item). This can be done as of patch 4.3 of Cataclysm.

Comment: Although, to transmog requires that the BoP item is the armor type that you use (Plate, Mail, Leather or Cloth), but the stats does not matter and have no effect at all on the outcome of the transmog. There are additional rules to transmogging, but that is out of scope for the question at hand.

Comment: BoE items that drop from trash mobs in LFR/LFD currently only stay as BoE if won by a greed roll. If the item is rolled on as a Need roll, it is changed to BoP automatically. This was implemented to stop ninja looting of items that could be sold for decent gold on the auction house.